# values methods in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Instead of using method all(), I want to use method values() to do an optimal search within the database, and I only want to get two fields from my model.
One of my fields is related to price, which is obtained by subtracting the original price from the discount. How can I access this field inside method values.
The error the project gives me: Cannot resolve keyword 'total_price' into field

```
my model :

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    unit_price = models.IntegerField()   
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        if not self.discount:
            return self.unit_price
        elif self.discount:
            total = (self.discount * self.unit_price) / 100
            return int(self.unit_price - total)
        return self.total_price


my view : 
   products = Product.objects.values('name','total_price')
```

Comment: There is no `total_price` field. You implemented such field, but then you overwrote it with the propery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I access this field inside method values. The error the project gives me: Cannot resolve keyword 'total_price' into field.

There is no `total_price` field. You specified such field, but overwrote it with a property, so that means that when the class is constructed, `total_price` is *not* a field, but a property.

If you want to minimize bandwidth, you can make use of [**`.only(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) to specify that you only want to retrieve a subset, so:

```
Product.objects.only('title', 'unit_price', 'discount')
```

,

but here in order to calculate the `total_price`, we thus need the `discount` and the `unit_price`, since you also want the `name` (`title`?), there is thus not much columns we should not retrieve.

That being said, unless a field contains a long amount of text, limiting the number of columns will not boost efficiency that much. Typically the *number* of queries determines how efficient a view runs, since network *bandwidth* is quite high, it is more the *delay* over a network that is a limiting factor.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions. My field name was name, which I mistyped.